# How to find a particular value from a string

Tags: php, string, parsing, find

I have a string (**not xml** )

```
<headername>X-Mailer-Recptid</headername>
<headervalue>15772348</headervalue>
</header>
```

from this, i need to get the value `15772348`, that is the value of `headervalue`. How is possible?

Comment: You say you do not have xml, but what you present is definitely some kind of XML structured code. So if you have a XML structured document you should use the relying parser.

Comment: Could it be, that you have a HTTP Header, and show it as XML to us, but you actually talk about a HTTP Header?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Use [PHP DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and traverse the `headervalue` tag using [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php):**

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML('<headername>X-Mailer-Recptid</headername><headervalue>15772348</headervalue></header>');

$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('headervalue');

for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
    echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "\n";
}
?>
```

This gives the following **output**:

> 15772348

**[EDIT]:** Code updated to suppress non-HTML warning about invalid headername and headervalue tags as they are not really HTML tags. Also, if you try to load it as XML, it totally fails to load.

Comment: it output the answer, but also getting some warning





Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML() [function.DOMDocument-loadHTML]: Tag headername invalid in Entity, line: 1 in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 496



Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML() [function.DOMDocument-loadHTML]: Tag headervalue invalid in Entity, line: 1 in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 496



Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML() [function.DOMDocument-loadHTML]: Unexpected end tag : header in Entity, line: 1 in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 496

Comment: @Linto, I have updated the code to suppress the warning. Try new code now.

Comment: It will fail to load as XML because there is no root element.

Comment: @Boltclock: yes, that's why I made it clear by editing the edit :)

Answer (score 2):

This looks XML-like to me. Anyway, if you don't want to parse the string as XML (which might be a good idea), you could try something like this:

```
<?
$str = "<headervalue>15772348</headervalue>";
preg_match("/<headervalue\>([0-9]+)<\/headervalue>/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: It's ok for simple things like this, but obligatory warning about using regular expressions to parse non-regular languages. [That way lies madness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 1):

// find string short way

```
function my_url_search($se_action_data)
    {
        // $regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
           $regex="/<headervalue\>([0-9]+)<\/headervalue>/"
         preg_match_all($regex, $se_action_data, $matches);
         $get_url=array_reverse($matches[0]);
         return array_unique($get_url);
    }
echo my_url_search($se_action_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       <?php
      $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html = str_get_html("<headername>X-Mailer-Recptid</headername>headervalue>15772348</headervalue></header>");        // Use Html dom here 
        $get_value=$html->find("headervalue", 0)->plaintext;
        echo $get_value;

    ?>



  http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find
```